# Python pitch shifting with Windows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, audio, librosa

I am attempting to create a sort of autotune/pitch correction algorithm in Python. I am able to detect pitches per a rectangular window size, and tried shifting the pitch of each window (of size 512) by 2 semitones to test if this method would actually work. Doing this, however, creates a huge amount of feedback in the returned audio. I assume this is due to the presence of a rectangular window, instead of a hanning window. My question is, how do I implement pitch correction on bins while also removing the feedback?

Code:

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import IPython.display as ipd
import random

samples, sr = librosa.load('my_raw_vocals.wav',sr=None)

def manipulate(data, sampling_rate, pitch_factor):
    return librosa.effects.pitch_shift(data, sampling_rate, pitch_factor)

def block(array, size):
  c = []
  array = list(array)
  for i in range(0,len(array) // size):
    frames = array[i*size:i*size+size]
    np_frames = np.asarray(frames)
    c.append(np_frames)
  perc_remainder = (len(array) / size) - (len(array) // size)
  if perc_remainder != 0:
    n_remainder = perc_remainder * size
    remainders = np.asarray(array[-1 * int(n_remainder):])
    c.append(remainders)
  return c

block512 = block(samples,512)

summation = []

rate = 2
for i in block512:
  altered_frame = manipulate(i,sr,r)
  summation.append(altered_frame)

frame_pitched512 = np.ndarray.flatten(np.asarray(summation))
frame_pitched512 = [val for sublist in summation for val in sublist]
frame_pitched512 = np.asarray(frame_pitched512)
ipd.Audio(frame_pitched512, rate=sr)
```

Actual audio and code is here:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cpRhPpvXY_9XZidjOLKk_wW15EnkqLEX?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

There should be a few things that I noticed about the total code:

1- Hamming window is a better choice in sound processing and rectangular windows is the worst by no doubt.

2- There should be a normalization `array/max(abs(array))` in order to receive an acceptable  answer

3- You should apply pre-emphasis for speech (just for speech)

4- Another important thing is to use robust pitch detection which can be implemented by many ways that is shown below:

It is odd that pitch changes more than 30% per frame so these pitches that are too big or too large are actually 2x or 0.5x of the actual pitch. So you should apply **pitch tracking** to ensure true results.